# jquery selector efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<!-- script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $parent = $("#parent");
    //$parent().dosomething()   
    // ... use $parent do something

    //!!! now i want use child !!!
    var $child = $parent.find("#child"); //method  one
    var $child = $("#child");           //method two
    //$child().dosomething()  
</script>
```

Question: method one  or  method two is better ??(hope explanation in detail ,thanks!)

waiting for your help

Comment: Test it yourself at jsPerf.

Comment: Id's are unique, so it should be faster to use `$('#id')`

Comment: Also, in method 1 the parent node is cached, so the DOM doesn't have to be requeried at all!

Comment: @elclanrs - but since he already has a reference to the $parent node, wouldn't it be faster to search for the #child ID only within the $parent node, rather than within the whole document? Of course, this is mostly academic - I think the efficiency difference is negligible.

Comment: i think method 2 faster; because it has less `code writing` and probably `less DOM traversal`.

Comment: Derp.  I was wrong.  Method 2 looks like it's faster.  http://jsperf.com/find-vs-unique-id

Comment: When you search DOM by unique ids, jquery uses native js method getElementById() which is fast, so no need to use the method 2 times, if it makes sense. Would be different if you deal with classes or tag names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**here**](http://jsperf.com/child-selector-speed) is a breakdown of what would be fastest. It shows that the `$parent.find` method is about 50% slower than the direct selector method. That means that if you've got to do with ids at all, it's quite significantly faster to just use the selector on its own.

Comment: your explanation is very details. i am a beginner. thanks for your help, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As elclanrs said, as each ID must be unique, it's more efficient to call directly the ID selector (method two) than calling the find() function.  Moreover, the find() function will get all the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector (in this case it wouldn't be a good idea cause you are requesting just one element, filtered by its ID, which once again, must be unique).  Method one will be useful just if you need to get more than one element inside the parent div, like `<li>` selectors, elements of the same class, etc.